# Select power supply voltage using MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, switches

I have a circuit which I wish to power using 5V or 1.8V or power off entirely.

For a simpler version, switching one voltage, I decided to use a P-channel mosfet as a high-side switch (see the left half of the schematic).

Then, I added a second mosfet connected to 1.8V. If I understand correctly, when the left (5V) mosfet is opened, current will flow through the load, but also through the internal body diode of the right mosfet back to the 1.8V supply - regardless of the voltage at the right gate. Am I right?

How can I redesign the circuit to avoid this problem? A simple diode would work but that adds a significant voltage drop which I hoped to avoid.

[image: schematic]

Comment: What about a relay? It doesn't sound like you need switching speed.

Comment: An electromagnetic relay would be too bulky for my board. Perhaps a small solid-state relay? But a mosfet or two seems simpler (and cheaper).

Comment: How small does it need to be, or how much current are we talking about? relays can be quite small these days: http://www.yoctopuce.com/projects/yoctorelay/img/illustr-yocto-relay-usb-big.jpg and a similar 10x6x5.65 mm one can switch up to 250VAC/5A/60W

Comment: Wow, that's small :) One of these would suffice as well.

Comment: How about connecting the MOSFETs, upside down.? Connecting drain to power supply and source to GND, will avoid the problem of conducting body diode.

Comment: Excellent question and answer; I found it useful in a similar problem: http://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/switching-a-choice-of-supply-voltage-pesky-body-diodes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second mosfet in series with the 1.8V one, but upside-down, wire the gates in parallel.  Mosfets don't mind passing "backwards" current when they are turned on. and when it's turned off it will keep the 5v out of the 1.8V

Comment: Will the second mosfet have a lower "backwards" voltage drop when it's turned on?

Comment: forwards and backwards resistance will be about the same when turned on.