# Reverse current protection on power-switching MOS

Tags: mosfet, switches, circuit-protection

It was suggested in "[Select power supply voltage using MOSFETs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150076/select-power-supply-voltage-using-mosfets)" that a second MOSFET can be added in series to prevent reverse current flow.

My question is, can I just reverse Drain and Source on the switching MOSFETs and not need extra MOS or diode?

[image: voltage selection circuit]
.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just reverse Drain and Source then in normal operation the body diode will conduct, even when the FET is switched off!

The solution is to wire two FETs 'back-to-back' so that their body diodes are in opposition, like this:-

[image]

Comment: Is there a difference between "body diodes pointing at each other" and "body diodes pointing away from each other"? I searched online and have seen both in use in reverse-protection circuit.

Comment: To control both FETs with the same Gate voltage the body diodes must point towards each other (or away from each other when using N-channel FETs). If each FET has a separate Gate drive circuit then the diodes may point the other way.

Comment: @BruceAbbott How do you choose between 2 N-channel or 2 P-channel if they're both being used in the same place in the circuit?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to switch them on with positive or negative voltage. Usually that means using P-channel for switching a positive supply rail, because the Gate is pulled down to Ground so it gets negative voltage (You could use N-channel, but then you would have to drive them with a Gate voltage _higher_ than the output voltage of the LM317).