# What is the purpose of MOSFETs in this schematic?

Tags: power, batteries, mosfet, charge

On the main power line there are two MOSFETs but for what reason?

[image]
<sub>(source: [www.ti.com](http://www.ti.com/ods/images/SLUSA78C/sys_sch_A_lusa78.gif))</sub>

The MOSFETs in question are Q1 and Q2.

Comment: Which two of the five are you referring to?

Comment: The very first 2 at the top left

Comment: you know why each component on a schematic has designators?

Comment: my bad q1 and q2 are the one's im referring to

Comment: Please make an effort to write proper English.  That includes capitalization and questions marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1, Q2 and Q5 are under host control and determine if battery is charging, and if 'System' is on or not. Q1 and Q2 select whether the battery or the adapter is sending power to U1. Q5 works with Q2 and both are 'ON' when the system is battery powered. U1 can be pulsed 'ON' (Q2 is 'ON') to maintain charge under load.
 This circuit can both charge the battery and supply system power if required. Todays smart phones can both charge and play videos or surf the net at the same time. Older cell phones had to charge first before you could use the phone as a phone, or send messages, etc.
 The newer charger IC's (U1) can handle the extra load of doing both task at the same time. If the phone is just charging, Q2 and Q5 will be 'OFF'. The user turning on the phone will cause Q5 and Q2 to come on in the proper order to supply system power.
 If the adapter is not plugged in or the battery is at full charge then Q1 is 'OFF'

Comment: Your welcome. You cannot discuss Q1 and Q2 without including Q5. I just wanted that detail to be included as it is a fundamental part of this circuits operation.

Answer (score 2):

A power MOSFET has got a parasitic [body diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_MOSFET#Body_diode).  Often, body diodes are implied and not drawn on circuit diagrams for brevity.  If we draw a P-channel MOSFET with a body diode, it looks like this.

[image]

Due to the body diode, a power MOSFET can block current only in one direction.  When you put a pair of MOSFETs back-to back, they can block current in either direction.

[image]
(image from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/178535))

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is for "Break before Make" logic to control the source of your system. In the schematic shown above, there is a SMBus power management IC or controller of some sort that will select the system source. Typically the two mosfets on the top left  will be lifted before a connection to the  battery is made with Q3 to prevent damage to it.

Comment: Thank you, im using this circuit to power a computer from a battery when its not plugged in, i just need to understand it better

Comment: read this http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt546/slyt546.pdf
The same principles apply in your application. I love these parts, they work very well! They greatly simplify the design process. LT has some good ones too.

Comment: 2 mosfets source to source to allow stopping the current in both directions. A single one can stop only in one direction